# ArgumentError rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a module that returns an array:

```
module Module1
  class Class1

    def self.get

      num << 1

      return num

    end

  end
end
```

But when I call it from the controller like this:

```
  def index

    @trans = Module1::Class1.get()

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render @trans }
    end
  end
```

Show me the following error:

```
'1' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.
```

But if I do in json:

```
  def index

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render Module1::Class1.get() }
    end
  end
```

It returns the right result, what am I doing wrong in the first example?

Comment: The class that you have posted in wont actually run. (num is an undefined local variable) so I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here. Otherwise I could give you some advice on how to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I want to display the result of an array from a module method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
format.json { render :json => @trans }
```